# Small font size (console and grub)

Tags: grub2, nvidia, virtual-console

Grub menu  is very small, and the  same is when I open a terminal with ctl+alt+f3 (how do you call it btw.?). Almost impossible to read.

I have dell precision 3561 laptop:

- ubuntu 21.10 (dual boot with win10)
- Display: 15,6" IPS (**3840 x 2160**)
- Graphic: NVIDIA T600, 4GB
- nvidia-driver-510

I think I saw somewhere in the documentation of the Ubuntu how to fix this issue, but could not find it again.

Comment: Did you try `gnome-tweaks` → **Fonts**?

Comment: I see only the options to change font size for gnome, but I need for grub and VT.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

The fonts are tiny because of your 3840 x 2160 display characteristics.

Try this...

Edit /etc/default/grub:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Find the line that looks like:

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

And change it to:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

**Note**: Change the size at the risk of GRUB not working correctly. It must be a size that your video card and video display supports.

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`

Comment: It sounds reasonable, but before I try this, what you mean "GRUB not working correctly" and what cannot I do then.

Comment: @as5 If you pick an invalid resolution size, GRUB won't display properly, and you'd have to do some minor gymnastics to rectify it.

Comment: So this approach solved my problem partly:
GRUB menu and GRUB prompt are indeed responding to this change. However, the tty console stays same.
Maybe I'll try the suggestion with fonts by @WU-TANG below but I'd rather say it seems to be the resolution issue as well. So any ideas on this?

Comment: Also I'd recommend first find out which resolutions are available as stated here: https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-safely-change-grub2-screen-resolution/ (I recommend to make a photo of this).
In my case it was 1024x768 that was good enough for me.

Comment: I tried to add 
`GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768 `
as desribed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ChangeTTYResolution 
with no effect on tty3

Comment: @as5 No more ideas. Sorry. You can certainly try WU-TANG's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two distinct questions here.

To change the font-size of the console:

It seemed like there may be more involved, the more I researched it, but all it took for me to increase the size was to edit **/etc/default/console-setup**.

changing or adding the line:

> FONTSIZE="8x16"

to

> FONTSIZE="16x32"

and then `sudo update-grub`

and then rebooting.
(consult the man page `man console-setup` for acceptable options)

You can also use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` to configure the console font.

---

You can change the font size of the grub menu with `grub-mkfont`

**Quick Guide:** if you know where the font location is.

`sudo grub-mkfont --output=/boot/grub/fonts/Myunifont32.pf2 --size=32 /home/username/Downloads/unifont-14.0.01.ttf`

Then edit /etc/update/grub adding:

> GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub/fonts/Myunifont32.pf2

`sudo update-grub`

Then reboot and your changes should be present.

**Background info/long instructions:**

You will probably need to know where the fonts are stored so you can reference them.

Use `fc-list` for that.

If you have a font in mind, then grep for that font name in the output. Note: Using a custom font will take some trial and error to get a "pretty" grub screen like you are used to. A lot of the fonts will work and be readable, but the symbols used to create the appearance of "graphics" may not line up or be what you are used to.

Running `strings -a /boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2` shows **"Unifont Regular 16"**. I have had no luck finding Unifont on my machine so I found it in the repository and `sudo apt install unifont`. This will make it show up in the `fc-list` output.

Once you've decided on which font you want to use: (for example, for unifont)

> ```
> fc-list | grep -i unifont
> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/unifont.ttf Unifont:style=Medium
> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/unifont_upper.ttf Unifont Upper:style=Medium
> /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/unifont_csur.ttf: Unifont CSUR:style=Medium
> ```

Or if you downloaded it:
It would be in whatever folder you downloaded it to: (I also found it  [here](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/unifont/))
/home/username/Downloads/unifont-14.0.01.ttf

Now you know where your font is located, you can use it to create one for grub and size it:

(The output [should] goes into the **/boot/grub/fonts** directory with your own customized filename, so you will need sudo)

`sudo grub-mkfont --output=/boot/grub/fonts/Myunifont32.pf2 --size=32 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/unifont/unifont.ttf`

Now you will need to reference your new font in the file **/etc/default/grub**.

Edit that file (as sudo) by whichever means you use (ie `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`)

and add the line:

> GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub/fonts/Myunifont32.pf2

Save the file and exit.

Then run `sudo update-grub`

...and then reboot and you should see your font change...

Depending on which font you decided to go with, you may have to do the process over again and over again to make adjustments. (it takes a few seconds once you get a rhythm). I tried to shortcut the process by making a common name "MYFONT" in /etc/default/grub and in /boot/grub/fonts just making a link from MYFONT to the actual font. That way I could just create 10 of them to test all at one time and then change the link each time I wanted to test a new one, without having to `sudo update-grub`... THAT DID NOT WORK, even with the link pointing to a new file, I had to `sudo update-grub` to see my changes... so something to keep in mind.

The unifont.ttf seems to be the closest and it looks fine, but right off the bat in the fc-list output you can see "Medium" vs the "Regular" in the unicode.pf2 strings output... That tells me they are not exactly the same. I figure the original font has to be SOMEWHERE in there but I cannot find it. If you stumble across it, post it here. I have looked on a bunch of sites and it seems no one else has been able to identify it either.

Comment: For the TTY issue I could make it better, see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1396532/increase-tty-resolution
This is basically your approach. I just used `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`