# Increase TTY resolution

Tags: nvidia, display-resolution, 21.10, tty

My default resolution might be to high and consequently the text is much to small. I managed to increase the resolution for [GRUB menu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1394984/723091) But still struggling with TTY.

I tried:

- add `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768` to `/etc/default/grub` as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ChangeTTYResolution):  with no effect
- Additionally add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"` as described [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-increase-tty-console-resolution-on-ubuntu-18-04-server). The effect was that I boot into a black screen with blinking cursor. I was basically able to log in via tty (however, multiple times the screen switched back to the blinking cursor). After I uncommented `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"` I was able to access Ubuntu GUI. But the TTY was really larger.

So it would be great if I could increase TTY and be able to access the Ubuntu GUI (GNOME, Unity?).

I have dell precision 3561 laptop running Ubuntu 21.10 (dual boot with win10)

- Display: 15,6" IPS (3840 x 2160)
- Graphic: NVIDIA T600, 4GB
  nvidia-driver-510

Comment: [This answer may still work](https://askubuntu.com/a/173221/1222991) 

Comment: Yes,  I managed to make it better with `Terminus` and largest available font. On external monitor you can now work quite good. On the laptop it is still way to small but acceptable. Basically, I think some approach with resolution would be better here.